# How to get one sheet data to other sheet mathcing certain values

Tags: excel

Sheet 1:

| Login name | Login date |
| --- | --- |
| Values in 60 rows | Values from Sheet 2 |

Sheet 2:

| Login date | Login name |
| --- | --- |
| Values in 60 rows | Values in 60 rows |

Please advise.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Index/Match, Vlookup, Filter all these formula should give you desired result. I would like to use `INDEX/MATCH` like-

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!B:B,0))
```